# How to know the current IME in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, ime, android-input-method

I want to know what IME is using currently in android.

I tried InputMethodManager.getEnabledInputMethodList(), 
but I can only get the list of IMEs.

I can't figure out how to determine which one is currently selected of the list.

How can I get which input method had selected currently?

Comment: Refer this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744729/how-to-determine-the-current-ime-in-android/4256571#4256571> Or this answer for previous question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744729/how-to-determine-the-current-ime-in-android/2744865#2744865>

Answer (score 2):

You can get a default IME, use:

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
```

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256571/3162918) answer says.

Answer (score 0):

InputMethodManager.getEnabledInputMethodList()